# Razor syntax shorthand for @Code

Tags: razor, razor-2

Is there a VB Razor (.vbhtml) syntax that is shorthand for `@Code ... End Code`, 

such as the C# `@{ }` ?

This would be for MVC 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The reason that the C# version appears shorter is that C# is generally less verbose than VB and braces `{ }` are part of its syntax.

Most IDEs with code-completion options turned on will save you the trouble of having to type `End Code` anyway, but if you really want "shorter", the best answer is to learn/use C#.

Comment: I know C# just fine.  I'm just one of those weirdos that prefer VB :)  Also, VB has braces too:  Dim something() As String = {"blah","blah"}, or Dim yadda As List(Of Tweet) = New List(Of Tweet) From {new Tweet(), new Tweet()}

Comment: I noticed that you know C# just fine which is why I added "/use" after "learn".